# Confusing about successive Lorentz transformation by the approach in Sean Carroll's book

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

In the book "Spacetime and geometry", the author obtained an equality (1.42) on page 18
$$
\Lambda^{\mu}_{\,\, \nu'} \Lambda^{\nu'}_{\,\, \rho} = \delta^{\mu}_{\,\, \rho}.  \tag{1.42}
$$

If I consider successive Lorentz transformations in passive style
$$ x^{\mu} = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\,\, \nu} x^{\nu} = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\,\, \nu} \Lambda^{\nu}_{\,\, \rho} x^{\rho}, \tag{1}$$

by the (1.42) in Sean Carroll, the above equation can be simplified to
$$ x^{\mu} = \delta^{\mu}_{\,\, \rho} x^{\rho} = x^{\mu}. \tag{2} $$

Does it make things too simple? If I consider two rotations, I do not expect to obtain a Kronecker delta, but for a rotation with an angle as summation over two angles

Answer (score 0):

He is just being perverse in using non-standard notation in that he puts primes on indices relating to  the new frame. In his notation, combining two successive transformations will be
$$
{\Lambda^{\lambda'}}_\mu {\Lambda^{\mu'}}_\nu.
$$
So contrary to standard index usage, he is summing over two "repeated" indices --- one of which has a prime on it, while the other does not.

Comment: You might want to use a different number of primes in that case. Consider reference frames $\Sigma$, $\Sigma'$, $\Sigma''$, then transformations $x^{\mu'}={\Lambda^{\mu'}}_{\nu} x^\nu$ and $x^{\mu''}={\Lambda^{\mu''}}_{\nu'}x^{\nu'}={\Lambda^{\mu''}}_{\nu'}{\Lambda^{\nu'}}_{\sigma}x^\sigma$ are perfectly sensible expressions that respect the summation convention. Of course, the transformation matrices with different primed indices don't have the same components.

Comment: and if I used (1.42) again, xμ′′=Λμ′′ν′xν′=Λμ′′ν′Λν′σxσ will lead to $x^{\mu''} = \delta^{\mu''}_{\sigma} x^{\sigma}$, maybe I am still confusing

Comment: @RandomUser Again, the $\Lambda$'s are different matrices in this notation. Call the first one $\Lambda_{(1)}$ and the second $\Lambda_{(2)}$ (or A and B...) if you like. They are completely independent and not inverse to each other. The only thing that is true is then ${(\Lambda_{(1)})^{\sigma}}_{\mu'}{(\Lambda_{(1)})^{\mu'}}_\nu=\delta^\sigma_\nu$ (or for the second transformation labeled with (2) respectively, just add one prime at each index)

Comment: @go_science I see. (1.42) needs to be for the same matrix, e.g., $\Lambda_{(1)}\Lambda_{(1)}    $, not $\Lambda_{(1)}  \Lambda_{(2)}  $. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The power of this approach is that it automatically distinguishes the transformation from its inverse, so ${\Lambda^\mu}_{\nu'}$ brings you from frame $\Sigma'$ to $\Sigma$, whereas ${\Lambda^{\nu'}}_\rho$ brings you from $\Sigma$ to $\Sigma'$. In that sense, the symbol $\Lambda$ describes two different matrices. The formula you mention then simply represents the invertibility of the Lorentz tranform.

Of course, if you want $\Lambda$ to represent the same matrix and dont distinguish between primed and unprimed indices, it does not work. However, without the use of primed and unprimed indices, I don't know of any other notation that allows clear distinction between the components of a Lorentz transformation, its transposed (relevant for the defining property $\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda=\eta$, which then reads ${\Lambda_{\mu'}}^\mu\eta_{\mu\nu}{\Lambda^\nu}_{\nu'}=\eta_{\mu'\nu'}$) and its inverse. The transformation of elements in the dual space, usually written with lower indices like $\omega_\mu$ becomes $\omega_{\mu'}={\Lambda_{\mu'}}^\mu\omega_\mu$.

Comment: I tried to think in inactive transformation, such that only change coordinate to arrive at Eq. (1)&(2) in my post. Does Sean Carroll's (1.42) only works for active transformation? I think (1.42) would be fine for both active/inactive.

Comment: I should say passive, instead of inactive

Comment: @RandomUser The logic works both ways. If you transform the coordinates like $x^{\mu'}={\Lambda^{\mu'}}_{\nu}x^\nu$, you could also transform your basis with the inverse transformation, $e_{(\mu')}={\Lambda^{\sigma}}_{\mu'}e_{(\sigma)}$, such that $x^{\mu'}e_{(\mu')}={\Lambda^{\mu'}}_{\nu}x^\nu{\Lambda^{\sigma}}_{\mu'}e_{(\sigma)}=\delta^\sigma_\nu x^\nu e_{(\sigma)}$ is an invariant object. However (I'm not sure about that), he also introduces the notation $e_{(\nu')}={\Lambda_{\nu'}}^\mu e_{(\mu)}$, which clashes with the transformation of the components of dual vectors.